# Application not getting launched from the notification list in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, notifications, libnotify

I have a GTK application and I m creating the app notification for it using the Libnotify package. I have a scenario where my application triggers a notification and after the popup disappears, the notification is present in the notification list. Now I quit my application and click on the notification from the list, but this does not launch my application.

I have observed that when my application is running and then I m clicking the notification from the notification list, then the action associated with the close signal of the notification is getting executed. However, nothing happens if my application is not running.

Is there something I m doing wrong or Is this how the notifications work in ubuntu? I have the default Gnome environment.
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your [mcve] and what kind of debugging you've done with it.